# I have a sphere $S^2$, how can I define it?

Tags: notation

I'm not sure how to say, using proper mathematical notation, a sphere $S^2$ is equal to the basic unit sphere $1=x^2 + y^2 + z^2$. Just looking for a quick answer, thank you.

Comment: How can you define it? You just have defined it!

Comment: @JohnMiller Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using set builder notation:

$$S=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$$

If it is clear that the ambient space is $\Bbb R^3$ and you don't feel that it's necessary to specify it, a possible shortcut is simply

$$S=\{x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$$

Comment: Would it not be $x,y,z \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: @Tyler6 Not if you write brackets around, then the object is the whole triple, and as a triple it lives in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @Tyler6 there is no difference between saying $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ and saying $x\in \Bbb R$ and $y\in\Bbb R$ and $z\in \Bbb R$.  Saying $x,y,z\in\Bbb R$ is just shorthand for the second.  $\{(x,y,z)~|~x,y,z\in\Bbb R,~x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ is the same set as written in the post above.

Comment: Ah ok, I was just mistaken as I thought that since they were being treated as variables we couldn’t define them as a vector

Comment: @Tyler6 (continuation of JMoravitz and Dietrich's comments): but here you have to use this notation because each element of your sphere is represented by a triple $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Thank you, currently doing an assignment/essay for my teacher and he's asked to write it using no English only mathematics. It's becoming extremely tedious. But it is useful in understanding set builder notation/first-order logic etc.

Comment: @JohnMiller You're welcome. Then you should not use the shortcut version but the full one to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes that's what I'm using. However, I'm not sure how to reference you in my bibliography? As in a user from a specific StackExchange question.

Comment: @JohnMiller I don't think you need to reference anyone for that :) no one is going to ask. They will assume you knew or looked it up somewhere and that's fine.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Well thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes for $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}$ the cartesian equation for a sphere centered at the origin and with radius $R$ is

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$$

and more in general with center in $C=(a,b,c)$

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=R^2$$

Note that the equation is derived from Pytagorean Theorem, that is

$$R= \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference in notation between geometers (the number denoting the dimension of the coordinate space) and topologists (the number denoting the dimension of the surface).

See introduction [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html).